# AnyChart stock chart - date extend overflow on X axis

Tags: javascript, anychart

I am building stock charts with AnyChart and I am stuck in a problem.

I get my data mapping directly from a third party data provider and it works perfectly. I have built a chart where users can draw, insert figures etc. The users are requesting a solution where they can draw *into the future* and scroll into dates later than the newest date in the data. The problem for me is that the chart date range selector is following the dates in the data mapping - so my question is if it's possible to set the date `rangeSelector` manually?

An example can be seen here: https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/OMXCOP-BO/
On the example you can just scroll to the right and into *future* dates even though the data is not following.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work with anychart?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you can use `minimumGap()` and `maximumGap()` functions. [The article with live samples](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Scales#gaps) describes how it works.